# Взять уникальные записи

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть таблица, в которой указаны много информации в колонке. Названия колонки - `operators`, её значения могут быть совершенно разные, то ли число, то ли слово, и идут они в разрез - `1,5,7,WORD, 1312, 663, 5, WORD, 663`.

Необходимо получить уникальные записи, т.е. в данном случае их всего 6 (`1, 5, 7, WORD, 1312, 663`, остальные повторяются).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

подсчет - `count()`, уникальные `distinct`

```
select count(distinct operators) from mytable
```

Comment: возможно я ошибся в вопросе, это я знаю, я хотел получить эти записи. Обновил вопрос, хотя distinict помог и там

Comment: да, тогда просто `select distinct operators`